# Different buttons depending on current post type search

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, post-type

I'm trying to show different text for the buttons on my search.php page, depending on whether the post_class is product or post.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['post_class'])) {
    $type = $_GET['post_class'];
    if($type == 'product') {?>
                <div class="post_more">
                    <a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="qbutton small"><?php esc_html_e('Shop Now','bridge'); ?></a>
                </div>      
    <?php    
    } elseif($type == 'post') {?>
                <div class="post_more">
                    <a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="qbutton small"><?php esc_html_e('Read More','bridge'); ?></a>
                </div>   
    <?php }
}
?>
```

It's currently showing nothing though.

Addition:

I'm adding the full code of my page, in case it helps you to help me:

```
<?php 
$bridge_qode_options = bridge_qode_return_global_options();
$bridge_qode_blog_hide_comments = "";
if (isset($bridge_qode_options['blog_hide_comments'])) {
    $bridge_qode_blog_hide_comments = $bridge_qode_options['blog_hide_comments'];
}

$bridge_qode_blog_hide_author = "";
if (isset($bridge_qode_options['blog_hide_author'])) {
    $bridge_qode_blog_hide_author = $bridge_qode_options['blog_hide_author'];
}

$bridge_qode_like = "on";
if (isset($bridge_qode_options['qode_like'])) {
    $bridge_qode_like = $bridge_qode_options['qode_like'];
}
?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="post_content_holder">
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <div class="post_image">
                <a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="post_text">
            <div class="post_text_inner">
                <h3 itemprop="name" class="entry_title"><span itemprop="dateCreated" class="date entry_date updated"><meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserComments: <?php echo get_comments_number(bridge_qode_get_page_id()); ?>"/></span> <a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <div class="post_info">
                    

                    <?php $bridge_qode_category = get_the_category(get_the_ID()); ?>
                    <?php if(!empty($bridge_qode_category)){ ?>

                    <?php } 
                    ?>
                    <?php if($bridge_qode_blog_hide_author == "no") { ?>
                        <span class="post_author">
                                    <?php esc_html_e('by','bridge'); ?>
                            <a itemprop="author" class="post_author_link" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?></a>
                                </span>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if($bridge_qode_blog_hide_comments != "yes"){ ?>
                        <span class="dots"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></span><a itemprop="url" class="post_comments" href="<?php comments_link(); ?>" target="_self"><?php comments_number('0 ' . esc_html__('Comments','bridge'), '1 '.esc_html__('Comment','bridge'), '% '.esc_html__('Comments','bridge') ); ?></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if( $bridge_qode_like == "on" ) { ?>
                        <span class="dots"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></span><div class="blog_like">
                            <?php if( function_exists('bridge_core_like') ) bridge_core_like(); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if(isset($bridge_qode_options['enable_social_share'])  && $bridge_qode_options['enable_social_share'] == "yes") { ?>
                        <span class="dots"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></span><?php echo do_shortcode('[social_share]'); ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <?php
                    $bridge_qode_my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                    if ($bridge_qode_my_excerpt != '') {
                        echo bridge_qode_get_module_part( $bridge_qode_my_excerpt );
                    }
                ?>
                <?php if ( ! post_password_required() ) { ?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['post_class'])) {
    $type = $_GET['post_class'];
    if($type == 'product') {?>
            <div class="post_more">
                <a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="qbutton small"><?php esc_html_e('Shop Now','bridge'); ?></a>
            </div>      
    <?php    
    } elseif($type == 'post') {?>
            <div class="post_more">
                <a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="qbutton small"><?php esc_html_e('Read More','bridge'); ?></a>
            </div>   
    <?php }
} ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: seems like `$_GET['post_class']` is not set if you get nothing

Comment: @Stender how would I set it? I've obviously missed something in the codex

Comment: You can use instead the global wp_query object to make it work, see below:

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** This is about `post_type` in the query search so you can use:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;

// For testing (uncomment the line below)
// echo '<pre>'. print_r( $wp_query, true ) . '</pre>';

if( isset($wp_query->query['s']) && isset($wp_query->query['post_type'])
&& $wp_query->query['post_type'] === 'product' ) {?>
    <div class="post_more">
        <a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="qbutton small"><?php esc_html_e('Shop Now','bridge'); ?></a>
    </div>
<?php
} elseif( isset($wp_query->query['s']) && ! isset($wp_query->query['post_type']) ) {?>
    <div class="post_more">
        <a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="qbutton small"><?php esc_html_e('Read More','bridge'); ?></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Tested and works

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We're definitely moving in the right direction here. I can see the button again, but all of the buttons are "Read More". I have checked and I have product as a post_type.

Comment: @user7827187 For me it works just fine on last woocommerce version on Storefront theme… So maybe there is something custom in your theme or if you are using a third party plugin for search. I have added something for testing, that you can uncomment, to see what arguments are required as conditions on each IF statements (when you make a search for products or for posts)

Comment: I really appreciate you adding the code for me to see what arguments are required, but when I uncomment it I get a 500 error. I'm starting to think that maybe this isn't possible with the current theme I am using. I am going to switch to Storefront and see what happens.

Comment: You just have to uncomment the line below, the one with the code (as specified).

Comment: Yeah, I've done that. I'm going to update my question to show my full page code. Hopefully that'll make it a bit easier for you or someone else to figure it out.

Comment: @user7827187 I have removed my answer code from your edit in your question, as people can see my answer here, with your comments below my answer. So in your question they get your complete original extended code. I will try to find out later on what can be done.…

Comment: I got the output of $wp_query showing by using : echo $wp_query->request;


SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpcw_posts.ID FROM wpcw_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (((wpcw_posts.post_title LIKE '{xxx}') OR (wpcw_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '{xxx}') OR (wpcw_posts.post_content LIKE '{xxx}'))) AND wpcw_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'wcps', 'wcps_layout', 'portfolio_page', 'product') AND (wpcw_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wpcw_posts.post_author = 1 AND wpcw_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wpcw_posts.post_title LIKE '{xxx}' DESC, wpcw_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10